# JtextPane with a touch interface

Tags: java, touch, highlighting, mt4j

I'm developing a touch based windows 7 app using a tuio client-server setup and a touch library that extends multitouch 4 java.
One of the functionality I'm struggling with is to enable text highlighting when using touch.
I display a simple txt file using a JTextPane to display the text, the highlighting is done by through a drag action.
I get the clicked position where the drag event starts and then when it stops and tried to convert those coordinates to the text panel's space but I get different values from the ones that I should have, usually before the actual text.

The code I'm using to display the document is the following:

```
            //Create the JDialog that is the container of it
            window = new JDialog(parent);
            window.setUndecorated(true);

            //Create the JTextPane
            text = new JTextPane();
            text.setPage(newFile.toURI().toURL());
            text.setEditable(false);
            text.setHighlighter(null);

            //ScrollPane that will be used to display the text
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
            scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 700));

            window.getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            window.pack();
            window.setVisible(true);
            window.validate();
```

Where the JDialog parent is the main display component used in my app.

The drag is handled as follows:

```
    @Override
public boolean processGestureEvent(GestureEvent ge) {
    if((ge instanceof DragEvent) && this.component.isHighlight())
    {
        tapCount=0;
        if(this.component.isHighlight())
        {
            //do highlighting
            DragEvent drag = (DragEvent) ge;
            switch (drag.getId()) {
            case GestureEvent.GESTURE_STARTED:
                Point start = drag.getFrom();
                Point calcStart = new Point(start.x - compPosition.x, start.y - compPosition.y);
                startPos = this.textDisplay.viewToModel(calcStart);

                break;

            case GestureEvent.GESTURE_ENDED:
                Point end = drag.getTo();
                Point calcEnd = new Point(end.x - compPosition.x, end.y - compPosition.y);
                endPos = this.textDisplay.viewToModel(calcEnd);

                System.out.println("I have this positions:" + startPos + "/" + endPos);
                System.out.println("Should have " + this.textDisplay.getSelectionStart() + "/" + this.textDisplay.getSelectionEnd());
                System.out.println("And the text is: " + this.textDisplay.getText().substring(startPos, endPos));
                break;
            case GestureEvent.GESTURE_CANCELED:
                startPos = 0;
                endPos = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In which the compPosition is the JDialog's position that holds the text pane. I'm simulating touch with the mouse so the correct text position for the highlighting I'm getting from the built-in highlighting functionality of the text pane with mouse.

Is the problem because of the JDialog and the JScroll pane that somehow skews the conversion?
The coordinate system for the point's I get from the touch are with the origin in the top left corner of the screen and the text pane's coordinate system origin is in the same top lef corner.

Any ideas on how can I solve the problem? Any suggestions are appreciated.

LE:
I was doing something wrong in that I was adding the gesture processor when I initialized the component and it's position was (0,0) and only afterwards I moved it where I wanted to.

I changed the position calculations as follows:

```
    Point calcStart = new Point(start.x - this.component.getLocation().x, start.y -this.component.getLocation().y);
```

passing instead a reference to the actual component and getting the location when needed.

Answer (score 0):

try instead of

```
 Point calcStart = new Point(start.x - compPosition.x, start.y - compPosition.y);
```

to use

```
 Point calcStart = new Point(start.x, start.y);
```

i wonder how it gonna end, so give us some value of what you get

Comment: I tried that and weirdly it gave the same result ... so I'm guessing somehow the location was set to (0,0) , which might make sense since I initialize the gesture processor when I create the component and it's initial position being 0,0, only afterwards I move it to where I want it. Now I pass a reference of the component to the gesture processor and look for the location when I need it: Point calcStart = new Point(start.x - this.component.getLocation().x, start.y - this.component.getLocation().y); This apparently works so far. Thank you for the help :)